# How to divide a number with 999 in c?

Tags: c

I have a task that requires me to divide a number from 1 to 998 with 999. But, it requires me to give output for 3 decimals. If it repeated, Output the repeated value with `"..."` For example :

```
Input :
998
Output :
0.998... // because 998/999 = 0.998998998998998....

Input : 
1
Output :
0.001... // because 001 is repeated just output "0.001..."
```

My problem is, "maybe" my code couldnt detect which is the repeated one and which is not. So a numbers of testcase is wrong in this code.

This is my code :

```
int main()
{
    int x1,x2,x3;
    double a,b,c = 0; 
    scanf("%d",&x1); getchar();
    scanf("%d",&x2); getchar();
    scanf("%d",&x3); getchar();
    a = (double)x1/999; 
    a = (int)(a*1000) / 1000.0;

    b = (double)x2/999; 
    b = (int)(b*1000) / 1000.0;

    c = (double)x3/999; 
    c = (int)(c*1000) / 1000.0;

    printf("%.3lf...\n", a);
    printf("%.3lf...\n", b);
    printf("%.3lf...\n", c);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In online judge, it only gives me 50 score. Which fews testcase is false there.

Comment: I suggest you to simulate the division with integers, it's a little tedious, but I think is the better way to get all scores.

Comment: If 1/999 is equal to 0.001001001..., then any three digit number xyz divided by 999 will equal 0.xyzxyzxyz... In other words, **all** the values will have repeating decimals. Your problem is (I assume) that your `printf()` statements are rounding the values up half the time, which is not required. Something like `int x; scanf(" %d", &x); printf("0.%03d...\n", x);` should work.

Comment: This is a really, really, really hard problem in general, and especially if you represent the numbers as ordinary ints or doubles, and use ordinary floating-point multiplication.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage you should post this comment as answer

Comment: Is it required to be fixed point or floating point? Will you round the results or not?

Comment: Tricky cases: should  `333` should produce `0.3...` or `0.333...`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);

    return (x%111)? !printf("0.%03d...\n", x) : !printf("0.%d...\n", x/111);
}
```

### Input:

```
57
222
```

### Output:

```
0.057...
0.2...
```